# how to avoid the bbox limitations on a Mapquest XAPI request 

Tags: openstreetmap, xml, mapquest

I am doing the following: I send a request to the API-Server - over http as a response I get the following result - in XML

example: the following link gives back all the Nodes of the Type amenity=restaurant in XML-Format.Note: the bounding box (bbox) limits the area:

`http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]`

`http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]`

note - I do it with wget since the XAPI-service is down for maintenance

see here the results:_

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
<osm version='0.6' generator='xapi: OSM Extended API 2.0' xmlns:xapi='http://www.informationfreeway.org/xapi/0.6' xapi:uri='/api/0.6/node[amenity=restaurant|fast_food|pub|cafe][bbox=9.4908142,48.7810801,9.5660019,48.8387351]' xapi:planetDate='20100824' xapi:copyright='2010 OpenStreetMap contributors' xapi:license='Creative commons CC-BY-SA 2.0' xapi:bugs='For assistance or to report bugs contact 80n80n@gmail.com' xapi:instance='zappyOsm'>
<node id='721241970' lat='48.830856' lon='9.5116892' user='mabe75' timestamp='2010-05-04T19:01:28Z' uid='260302' version='1' changeset='4607010'>
<tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
<tag k='name' v='Lamm'/>
</node>
<node id='392682646' lat='48.8315734' lon='9.5468864' user='MattGPS' timestamp='2010-05-11T19:00:20Z' uid='12973' version='3' changeset='4671372'>
<tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
<tag k='name' v='Gasthaus an der Wieslauf'/>
</node>
<node id='319597380' lat='48.8277913' lon='9.5477029' timestamp='2008-12-17T21:13:15Z' version='1' changeset='444629'>
<tag k='amenity' v='restaurant'/>
<tag k='name' v='Gasthaus zur Linde'/>
</node>
[...]
```

well this example works pretty well - if I do it with wget.

question: how can I avoid the limitations of the bbox?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What do you mean delimit the limitations of the box? If you mean increase the size of the allowed box, that is impossible, as it's set on the server. Mapquest provide this service for free and presumably do not wish to allocate resources to unreasonably large requests.

Comment: hello dear stev_ thx alot. BTW - what bout the transfert into a mysql db. How can this little datachunk be transferred into a DB?

Comment: see my comment on your other question

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's impossible. Mapquest provide this service for free and quite reasonably do not wish to allocate resources to unreasonably large requests, as they would take up disproportionate server time and degrade the server for other users.

As an aside if you are doing this for either large amounts of data or frequently, you should consider using a database dump for the country you are interested in and then parsing it yourself using the [Osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) Java tool. Both to be a good citizen and also becuase I don't know if they throttle IPs or similar.

Comment: hi stev_k - many thanks - i will dig deeper into the osmosis